# Why in some Python built-in functions we using variables like string

Tags: python, built-in

For example

```
class c:
    var = 15

getattr(c, 'var')
```

or

```
i = 0
globals()['i'] = 25
```

why here our variable writing like string type.
I saw this in some built-in functions and in Django and i think this make code much difficulty for understanding isn't it?

Comment: Well, yeah, in these particular examples there's certainly a simpler way to do it. But `getattr` and `globals` has its uses if you're trying to work with unknown attributes/variables and/or set them dynamically.

Comment: what else would you like the **name** of a variable to be?

Comment: These approaches have their use, but yes, generally using dynamic variables makes code harder to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`globals()` returns a dictionary, so you have to use the variable name as string for looking at it. In `globals()['var']`, `'var'` is just a key in `globals()` returned dict, so it must be given as string.

`getattr(c, 'var')` looks for attribute `"var"` in `c.__dict__`.

Remember: Python makes a heavy us of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the variable names beforehand, and they are constant, then you can do both these things in a different way:

```
getattr(c, 'var')
```

This is a shorthand for:

```
try:
    return c.var
except AttributeError:
    if have_default: # hand-wavey "more to this" for a later lesson
       return default
    raise
```

and

```
globals()['i'] = 25
```

is a nasty way of doing

```
global i
i = 25
```

The method you've given is essentially reaching into the internals and fiddling around with them. using the `global` keyword is the better way to declare that you are use a variable in the global scope, because when the function is interpreted python knows that the variable is from a different scope at that point.

However if you don't know the name of the variable beforehand, then you'd be forced to do it the way in your examples. (but please, please think twice before using the `globals` one. Putting arbitrary variables in a module's global namespace at runtime? **shudders**)